PDF to SVG conversion not working (Crop the SVG output based on the content height and width)
I am facing the issue while convert PDF to SVG file conversion by using dvisvgm.exe.
I am getting the SVG output with the default page height and width, but I want to set the dimensions based on the content's width and height (each page contains only a single equation).
how to convert the svg file from pdf. I am using lualatex-dev for creating a pdf
I used the following syntax for PDF to SVG conversion.
dvisvgm.exe --pdf input.pdf -o output.svg
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}r(t) = \frac{dN}{dt} / N \quad \text{see in eq. 1}\end{equation*}

\clearpage
\begin{equation*}
\frac {dy} {dx} = f (x,y), \quad y(x_0) = y_0
\end{equation*}
\clearpage

$\lambda_t = \frac{N_{t+1}}{N_t}$

\end{document}

I am getting an SVG output with a width of 595.276pt and a height of 841.89pt, but the PDF content height is very small.


On my system, the pages of the PDF file are not small but have exactly the size you mentioned. Here's the media box info of the first page reported by mutool: [ 0 0 595.276 841.89 ]. Therefore, the SVG gets the same extents. Maybe you want to use standalone or a similar document class that creates tighter page boxes.

Dvisvgm only computes tight bounding boxes when processing DVI files. If you convert PDF or PostScript files, it applies their page extents to the generated SVG files.
To get similar result to the DVI conversion, it's therefore necessary to resize the PDF pages.
One possibility is to use the tightpage option of the preview package. Unfortunately, it only adapts the page heights and applies identical widths to all pages of the PDF file -- at least that's what I noticed when playing around with its options. This can be fixed with the varpage package. So, a possible solution could look like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newenvironment{page}
  {\begin{preview}\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}}
  {\end{varwidth}\end{preview}}

\begin{document}
\begin{page}
  \begin{equation*}
    r(t) = \frac{dN}{dt} / N \quad \text{see in eq. 1}
  \end{equation*}
\end{page}

\begin{page}
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac {dy} {dx} = f (x,y), \quad y(x_0) = y_0
  \end{equation*}
\end{page}

\begin{page}
  $\lambda_t = \frac{N_{t+1}}{N_t}$
\end{page}
\end{document}

$ dvisvgm -P test.pdf -p1-
processing PDF file
  graphic size: 120.574465pt x 22.57233pt (120.124bp x 22.488bp)
  output written to test-1.svg
processing PDF file
  graphic size: 117.235992pt x 22.57233pt (116.798bp x 22.488bp)
  output written to test-2.svg
processing PDF file
  graphic size: 44.28545pt x 15.16867pt (44.12bp x 15.112bp)
  output written to test-3.svg
3 of 3 pages converted in 0.110206 seconds

However, if you want to create SVG files using dvisvgm, I'd suggest to prefer DVI files because they lead to more reliable results in most cases and usually don't require additional tweaks to get tight SVG bounds.
